# How to remove duplicates in Pandas Data frame based on a Condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am making a small counting software that basically counts the the total number of people present inside a premises. The data frame I am getting from the microcontroller database (which allows people to go in and out) has a human error in which sometimes the user has exit before an Entry. So there are instances in the data frame where one entry has multiple exits before another subsequent entry. The df is something like this:

```
date     timestamp  type    cardno      status
**20201006  55737   PC010   117016056   Valid Card Exit**
20201006    55907   PC010   117016056   Valid Card Entry
20201006    60312   PC006   100024021   Valid Card Entry
20201006    61311   PC006   100024021   Valid Card Exit
20201006    61445   PC006   100024021   Valid Card Entry
20201006    61538   PC006   100024021   Valid Card Exit
20201006    61646   PC010   117016056   Valid Card Exit
20201006    61933   PC006   100024021   Valid Card Entry
20201006    61938   PC010   117016056   Valid Card Entry
20201006    62025   PC006   100024021   Valid Card Exit
20201006    62041   PC010   117016056   Valid Card Exit
20201006    62042   PC006   100024021   Valid Card Entry
20201006    62225   PC010   117016056   Valid Card Entry
20201006    62527   PC006   100024021   Valid Card Exit
20201006    63018   PC006   100024021   Valid Card Entry
20201006    64832   PC007   116057383   Valid Card Entry
20201006    64834   PC011   117016074   Valid Card Entry
**20201006  64952   PC012   116054003   Valid Card Exit**
```

The entries with ** is basically the employee hitting exit before an entry (for whatever reason) and that messes up the counting. I want to get rid of all such instances in the data frame. I am having a really hard time in going about doing this tbh. The counting software that I have made thus far basically reads a firebird database and then makes different data frames out of it, proceeds to count its shape, and then displays the output as a Simple HTML on a big Screen placed within the premises. The data frame I have described above having the issue is called 'contractorDf' in the program that I am running in production (testing) as below:

```
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd
import re
import os
import sys
   
#------------------------------------------------------PRODUCTION-----------------------------------------#
# Generating a Temporary Date for Production Environment
tempDate = date(2020, 10, 6)
tempDate = str(tempDate)
tempDate = tempDate.replace('-', '')
#------------------------------------------------------PRODUCTION----------------------------------------#
   
################################################################################################################################
# Getting Current Day (This will be used in real environment)
currentDay = datetime.now().day

if currentDay < 10:
    currentDay = str(currentDay)
    currentDay = '0'+ currentDay
else:
    currentDay = str(currentDay)


# Getting Current Year & Month
currentYear = datetime.now().year
currentMonth = datetime.now().month
currentYear = str(currentYear)
currentMonth = str(currentMonth)
currentYearMonth = currentYear+currentMonth
currentYearMonthDay = currentYearMonth+currentDay

# Getting Variable for After FROM
currentTableName = 'ST'+currentYearMonth

# Getting Final Query (Commented Right now because Testing)
query = "SELECT * FROM " + currentYearMonth + " " + "WHERE TRDATE=" + currentYearMonthDay + ";"
finalQuery = bytes(query, 'ascii')
#############################################################################################################################


#-------------------------------------------------------PRODUCTION------------------------------------------------------#
# Making a temporary Table Name and Query for Production Environment
tempTableName = 'ST'+currentYearMonth
nonByteQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + tempTableName + " " + "WHERE TRDATE=" + tempDate + ";"
tempQuery = bytes(nonByteQuery, 'ascii')
#-------------------------------------------------------PRODUCTION------------------------------------------------------#



# Generating record.csv file from command prompt (Before initiating this, C:\\Program Files (x86)\\FireBird\\FireBird_2_1\\bin should be in the environment variables)
p = subprocess.Popen('isql', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.write(b'CONNECT "C:\\Users\\JH\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\EntryPass\\P1_Server\\event\\TRANS.fdb";') #The italicized b is because its a Byte size code and we can't 
p.stdin.write(b'OUTPUT "C:\\Users\\JH\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\EntryPass\\P1_Server\\event\\record.csv";')
p.stdin.write(tempQuery)
p.stdin.write(b'OUTPUT;')
p.communicate()
p.terminate()
# Terminating the Command Prompt Window



# Reading the record file that is just generated above
tempdf = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\JH\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\EntryPass\\P1_Server\\event\\record.csv', sep='delimeter', engine='python', header=None, skipinitialspace=True)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

#tempdf = tempdf[0].astype(str)
columns = ["TRDATE", "TRTIME", "TRCODE", "TRDESC", "CTRLTAG", "CTRLNAME", "CTRLIP", "CARDNO", "STAFFNO", "STAFFNAME", "DEPTNAME", "JOBNAME", "SHIFTNAME", "DEVTYPE", "DEVNAME", "DEVNO", "TRID", "ISCAP", "RCGROUP", "POLLTIME", "SENDSEQ", "RECSEQ", "IOBNO", "IOBNAME", "ZONENO", "ZONENAME", "POINTNO", "POINTNAME", "ISSNAPRET", "PROTRAG"]
header = tempdf.iloc[0]
linespace = tempdf.iloc[1]
header = str(header)
header = header[5:]
header = header[:-24]
linespace = str(linespace)
linespace = linespace[7:]
linespace = linespace[:-23]

tempdf = tempdf[~tempdf[0].str.contains(header)]
tempdf = tempdf[~tempdf[0].str.contains(linespace)]
tempdf = tempdf[0].str.replace(' ', ',')
df = tempdf.str.split(",", n=400, expand=True)
df = df[[0,1,7,8,9,10,31,41,42,43,52,53,54]]
df[100] = df[7].map(str) + ' ' + df[8].map(str) + ' ' + df[9].map(str) + ' ' + df[10].map(str)
df = df.drop([7,8,9,10], axis=1)
df[101] = df[31].map(str) + df[41].map(str)
df = df.drop([31,41], axis=1)
df[102] = df[43].map(str) + df[52].map(str) + df[53].map(str) + df[54].map(str)
df = df.drop([43,52,53,54], axis=1)

def newblock(column):
    if column[42].startswith('VIS'):
        return column[42]
    else:
        pass


df = df.assign(newblock=df.apply(newblock, axis=1))

df[42] = df[42].str.replace('VIS_\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d', '')

df[105] = df[42].map(str) + df[101].map(str)
df = df.drop([42,101], axis=1)
df[106] = df[102].map(str) + df['newblock'].map(str)
df = df.drop(['newblock', 102], axis=1)
df[106] = df[106].str.replace('None', '')
df = df[[0,1,106,105,100]]
columns = ['date', 'timestamp', 'type', 'cardno', 'status']
df.columns = df.columns.map(str)
df.columns = columns
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.drop(['index'], axis=1)




#Making Visitor Counter
visitorDf = df[df['type'].str.startswith('VIS')]
#visitorDf = visitorDf[~visitorDf['status'].str.contains('Unknown')]
visitorIn1 = len(visitorDf[visitorDf['status'].str.contains('Unknown')])
VisitorIn1 = int(visitorIn1)
visitorDf = visitorDf.reset_index()
visitorDf = visitorDf.drop(('index'), axis=1)
visitorIn = len(visitorDf[visitorDf['status'].str.contains('Valid Card Entry')])
visitorOut = len(visitorDf[visitorDf['status'].str.contains('Valid Card Exit')])
visitorIn = int(visitorIn)
visitorOut = int(visitorOut)
totalVisitor = visitorIn1 + visitorIn - visitorOut

#Making Contractor Counter
contractorDf = df[df['type'].str.startswith('PC')]
#contractorDf = contractorDf[~contractorDf['status'].str.contains('Unknown')]
contractorIn1 = len(contractorDf[contractorDf['status'].str.contains('Unknown')])
contractorIn1 = int(contractorIn1)
contractorDf = contractorDf.reset_index()
contractorDf = contractorDf.drop(('index'), axis=1)
contractorIn = len(contractorDf[contractorDf['status'].str.contains('Valid Card Entry')])
contractorOut = len(contractorDf[contractorDf['status'].str.contains('Valid Card Exit')])
contractorIn = int(contractorIn)
contractorOut = int(contractorOut)
totalContractor = contractorIn1 + contractorIn - contractorOut


#Making Employee Counter
employeeDf = df[df['type'].str.contains('^\d', regex=True)]
#employeeDf = employeeDf[~employeeDf['status'].str.contains('Unknown')]
employeeIn1 = len(employeeDf[employeeDf['status'].str.contains('Unknown')])
employeeIn1 = int(employeeIn1)
employeeDf = employeeDf.reset_index()
employeeDf = employeeDf.drop(('index'), axis=1)
employeeIn = len(employeeDf[employeeDf['status'].str.contains('Valid Card Entry')])
employeeOut = len(employeeDf[employeeDf['status'].str.contains('Valid Card Exit')])
employeeIn = int(employeeIn)
employeeOut = int(employeeOut)
totalEmployee = employeeIn1 + employeeIn - employeeOut


os.remove('C:\\Users\\JH\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\EntryPass\\P1_Server\\event\\record.csv')

visitor = totalVisitor
employee = totalEmployee
contractor = totalContractor

if os.path.exists('C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\counter\\index.html'):
    os.remove('c:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\counter\\index.html')
else:
    pass

f = open('C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\counter\\index.html', 'w')

message = """
<html lang="en-US" class="hide-scroll">
    <head>
        <title>Emhart Counter</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
        body {{
            background-color: lightblue;
        }}

        .verticalCenter {{
            margin: 0;
            top: 100%;
            -ms-transform: translateY(25%);
            transform: translateY(25%);
        }}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <div class=“verticalCenter">
                <h1 style=font-size:100px>VISITORS: &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; {visitor}</h1><br></br><br></br>
                <h1 style=font-size:100px>EMPLOYEES: &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; {employee}</h1><br></br><br></br>
                <h1 style=font-size:100px>CONTRACTORS: &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp; {contractor}</h1><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br>
                <h3 style=font-size: 50px>THIS IS A TEST RUN<h3>
            </div>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>"""


new_message = message.format(visitor=visitor, employee=employee, contractor=contractor)
f.write(new_message)
f.close()


sys.exit()
```

The only problem left is how do I go about in getting rid of exits for a cardno/type before it has a corresponding Entry in the contractorDf. I would really really appreciate any help on the matter.

Comment: The latter sample code seems redundant.

Comment: Also, the double stars seems to be misleading. I assume they are not present in the original dataset.

Answer (score 0):

For your example [startswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html#pandas-series-str-startswith) and [endswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html#pandas-series-str-endswith) would work. For more complex regex-patterns use [contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas-series-str-contains).

```
mask = df.date.str.startswith("**")
print(df[mask])

# or

mask = df.status.str.endswith("**")
print(df[mask])
```

Outputs:

```
         date timestamp   type     cardno             status
0  **20201006     55737  PC010  117016056  Valid_Card_Exit**
3  **20201006     64952  PC012  116054003  Valid_Card_Exit**
```

Setup:

```
columns = ['date','timestamp','type','cardno','status']
data = [el.split(",") for el in ['**20201006,55737,PC010,117016056,Valid_Card_Exit**',
'20201006,55907,PC010,117016056,Valid_Card_Entry',
'20201006,64834,PC011,117016074,Valid_Card_Entry',
'**20201006,64952,PC012,116054003,Valid_Card_Exit**']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

### The Cumsum Trick

The key to the problem is a commonly-seen mathematical trick. We first regard `entry` as `1`, and `exit` as the cancellation of entry, namely `-1`. Then an exit event is bad **if** it first produces a negative cumulative sum (`cumsum`) up to that row. I.e., when the exit event happened cannot be interpreted as a proper cancellation of a previous entry. However, note that subsequent negative `cumsum` values can be caused by previous bad values. Therefore, we identify ONLY the first negative cumsum value as bad.

Based on the observation above, one can find the first bad entry for each card in a recursive manner until no negative cumsum value is produced.

### Code

The implementation demonstrates how to do this recursively. It is not quite optimized for large datasets, but the virtue should be somehow similar.

```
# initialize
df["retain"] = True
df["delta"] = -1
df.loc[df["status"] == "Valid Card Entry", "delta"] = 1

def recurse(df):

    # sort for cumsum (bad values found were not retained)
    df_sorted = df[df["retain"]].sort_values(by=["cardno", "timestamp"]).reset_index(drop=True)

    # cumsum
    df_sorted["cumsum"] = df_sorted[["cardno", "delta"]].groupby("cardno").cumsum()

    # get the first occurrence of negative cumsum
    df_dup = df_sorted[df_sorted["cumsum"] < 0].groupby("cardno").first()

    # termination condition: no more bad values were found
    if len(df_dup) == 0:
        return

    # else, remove the bad rows
    for cardno, row in df_dup.iterrows():
        df.loc[(df["cardno"] == cardno) & (df["timestamp"] == row["timestamp"]), "retain"] = False

# execute    
recurse(df)

del df["delta"]  # optional cleanup
```

### Output

See the "retain" column (`False` = bad exits).

```
df
Out[61]: 
        date  timestamp   type     cardno            status  retain
0   20201006      55737  PC010  117016056   Valid Card Exit   False
1   20201006      55907  PC010  117016056  Valid Card Entry    True
2   20201006      60312  PC006  100024021  Valid Card Entry    True
3   20201006      61311  PC006  100024021   Valid Card Exit    True
4   20201006      61445  PC006  100024021  Valid Card Entry    True
5   20201006      61538  PC006  100024021   Valid Card Exit    True
6   20201006      61646  PC010  117016056   Valid Card Exit    True
7   20201006      61933  PC006  100024021  Valid Card Entry    True
8   20201006      61938  PC010  117016056  Valid Card Entry    True
9   20201006      62025  PC006  100024021   Valid Card Exit    True
10  20201006      62041  PC010  117016056   Valid Card Exit    True
11  20201006      62042  PC006  100024021  Valid Card Entry    True
12  20201006      62225  PC010  117016056  Valid Card Entry    True
13  20201006      62527  PC006  100024021   Valid Card Exit    True
14  20201006      63018  PC006  100024021  Valid Card Entry    True
15  20201006      64832  PC007  116057383  Valid Card Entry    True
16  20201006      64834  PC011  117016074  Valid Card Entry    True
17  20201006      64952  PC012  116054003   Valid Card Exit   False
```

For demonstration purpose, `cumsum`s before and after cleanup is shown below. The dataset is sorted by `(cardno, timestamp)`, and the `date` column is deleted for clarity.

**Before**

```
df_sorted
Out[69]: 
    timestamp   type     cardno            status  retain  delta  cumsum
0       60312  PC006  100024021  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
1       61311  PC006  100024021   Valid Card Exit    True     -1       0
2       61445  PC006  100024021  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
3       61538  PC006  100024021   Valid Card Exit    True     -1       0
4       61933  PC006  100024021  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
5       62025  PC006  100024021   Valid Card Exit    True     -1       0
6       62042  PC006  100024021  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
7       62527  PC006  100024021   Valid Card Exit    True     -1       0
8       63018  PC006  100024021  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
9       64952  PC012  116054003   Valid Card Exit    True     -1      -1
10      64832  PC007  116057383  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
11      55737  PC010  117016056   Valid Card Exit    True     -1      -1
12      55907  PC010  117016056  Valid Card Entry    True      1       0
13      61646  PC010  117016056   Valid Card Exit    True     -1      -1
14      61938  PC010  117016056  Valid Card Entry    True      1       0
15      62041  PC010  117016056   Valid Card Exit    True     -1      -1
16      62225  PC010  117016056  Valid Card Entry    True      1       0
17      64834  PC011  117016074  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
```

**After**

```
df_sorted
Out[73]: 
    timestamp   type     cardno            status  retain  delta  cumsum
0       60312  PC006  100024021  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
1       61311  PC006  100024021   Valid Card Exit    True     -1       0
2       61445  PC006  100024021  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
3       61538  PC006  100024021   Valid Card Exit    True     -1       0
4       61933  PC006  100024021  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
5       62025  PC006  100024021   Valid Card Exit    True     -1       0
6       62042  PC006  100024021  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
7       62527  PC006  100024021   Valid Card Exit    True     -1       0
8       63018  PC006  100024021  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
9       64832  PC007  116057383  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
10      55907  PC010  117016056  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
11      61646  PC010  117016056   Valid Card Exit    True     -1       0
12      61938  PC010  117016056  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
13      62041  PC010  117016056   Valid Card Exit    True     -1       0
14      62225  PC010  117016056  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
15      64834  PC011  117016074  Valid Card Entry    True      1       1
```